# GNUPLOT : Plotting a user defined equations which operates indifferent intervals

Tags: function, plot, gnuplot, intervals

Hi there I need some help! 
I am new to Gnuplot and have difficulties with the scripts.
Actually my equation is a lot more complicated. It is a parametric equation consisting of 7 parts each defined into a specific interval, with a bunch of parameters. 
I just need a lead. So let me simplify the problem. 
Suppose I have a function defined as follows f(x)= a*x+cos(x)  : for 0 <= x <= 3;
and f(x)= b*1/cos(x) :  for 3 < x <=10
my question is how do I instruct GNUPLOT: 
1-) to consider "a" and "b" as parameters
2-) to plot "my user-defined" equation into the intervals of definition of f(x)
So far I have used the "**set parametric**" command but the problem is always at the end at the "**PLOT f(x)**" command for which I really don't know how to deal with the intervals. 
I am using Windows 7 with the latest **gnuplot**. 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `f(x)` as a (conditional) piece-wise function:

```
f(x) = 0 <= x && x <= 3 ? a*x+cos(x) : 3 < x && x <= 10 ? b/cos(x) : 1/0
```

The `1/0` above makes sure the function is not defined outside of the given intervals. The parameters `a` and `b` are already implicitly treated as parameters by gnuplot. When you change their values, `f(x)` is updated automatically. Example:

```
set xrange [-2:12]
a = 1.; b = 1.
plot f(x)
```

[image]

If you want more flexibility, you can take `a` and `b` as variables and do the following:

```
f(x,a,b) = 0 <= x && x <= 3 ? a*x+cos(x) : 3 < x && x <= 10 ? b/cos(x) : 1/0
set xrange [-2:12]
plot f(x,1,1), f(x,2,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much **Miguel**, Your answer is Perfect. It works like a charm.

I am really grateful.